# How can I make UIBarButtonItem image transparent?

Tags: xcode, png, transparency, uibarbuttonitem

I'd like to use the attached png as an image of an UIBarButtonItem.
I'd like to set its black background as transparent, but I can't find any way to set it as mask color in XCode. How can I make it transparent? Thanks very much!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way it to make the black background transparent in Photoshop and use it in the project. I use it that way and it works fine for me.